# No space between elements in a Thymeleaf each loop

Tags: thymeleaf

With Thymeleaf when I do :

`<span th:each="item : ${X}">1</span>`

I get :

```
<span>1</span>
<span>1</span>
<span>1</span>
...
```

How can I have this :

`<span>1</span><span>1</span><span>1</span>...`

?

Comment: In Thymeleaf 3 we now have the opposite problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is processed with a new line due the next issue, to improve readability:

- https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/113

At the moment, I don't think you could avoid the break line without patching it. So, if you want to have this behavior you could patch the class `AbstractIterationAttrProcessor`. How? Just create a class with the same name and package in your project, and copy the content of the original one:

- Package: `org.thymeleaf.processor.attr`
- Class Name = `AbstractIterationAttrProcessor`

Then change the conditional in line 133 to avoid the new line if it is an span element. It would be like next:

```
if (preserveWhitespace && index > 0 && !element.getOriginalName().equals("span")) {
      parentNode.insertBefore(element, new Text(whitespace));
}
```

I've just added `!element.getOriginalName().equals("span")` to the condition.  With this patch your span will be processed as:

```
 <span>1</span><span>1</span>
```

---

I've opened an issue due your question:

- https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/586

Comment: Thanks Pau for your answer